# How to override ADF parameters at scale in Azure DevOps deployment?

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, azure-data-factory, cicd, azure-rm-template

I'm currently building a CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps to build and deploy Azure Data Factory objects across different environments but I'm not really sure how to handle the parameters of the pipelines during the CD part.

The thing is as follows:

1. ADF pipelines contain parameters with different values:

- param_1: "param1-dev"
- param_2: "param2-dev"
- param_3: "12345'

2. The CI process is triggered every time a change is published in ADF. That means the ARM template from ADF is updated with the structure of the ADF + all the parameters.
3. The CD process deploys all the objects across different environments of ADF. For the TST environment, for example, these should be the values of the parameters:

- param_1: "param1-tst"
- param_2: "param2-tst"
- param_3: "67890'

Azure DevOps offers the possibility to use the `overrideParameters` option inside the `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` task. It looks like this:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ADF - Deploy ARM templates to TST'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'tst-connection'
    subscriptionId: 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    resourceGroupName: 'tst-resource-group'
    location: 'West Europe'
    csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ArmTemplates/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ArmTemplates/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters: '-param_1 "param1-tst"
                         -param_2 "param2-tst"
                         -param_3 "67890"'
```

And the same for the PRD environment.
This is quite useful but when your ADF grows it's not really scalable since you need to manually update this string every time you create a new parameter (which also implies that you will be modifying the CI/CD continuously).

One workaround for those parameters with values linked to the environment would be to create a global parameter in ADF with the name of the environment and then make use of it in all the pipelines. This works for `param_1` and `param_2` but not for `param_3` since its value is not linked to the env and is just a random ID (not a secret/token, for those we use KeyVault).

I was thinking on creating a config file with a list of all the parameters and their values per environment (manually maintained) and add a custom script before the deployment task to parse that list and update the ARM template, so there will be no need to use the `overrideParameters` anymore. This could be an improvement of the current situation since you are not continuously changing your CI/CD but I'd like to avoid using custom scripts personally.

My question is: is there any other option to handle this? or best practices to follow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, having a configuration file is the best way. Inside CD
> implementation itself you can read that configurations and use the
> values accordingly.

OR

> another way, would be tweaking your pipelines implementation. Have a
> configuration file with values for parameters and inside the ADF
> pipelines, first step would be checking the environment from global
> parameter and then based on env value read the configurations
> accordingly using `Lookup` activity.

Comment: What do you mean with "Inside CD implementation itself you can read that configurations and use the values accordingly"? to add  a custom script or is there any built-in option to do it?